# Entity framework update ICollection for self referencing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

When I try update database the property `Childrens` not saving but `SortOrder`
and display name are success.

This is my model:

```
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }        
    public Int64? LanguageId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LanguageId")]
    public Language Language { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Childrens")]
    public Int64? ParentId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Menu> Childrens { get; set; }
```

I called this function with new parameters:

```
 public void SaveMenu(List<Menu> newMenu)
    {
        foreach(Menu _addMenu in newMenu)
        {
            this.Update(_addMenu);
        }
        this.Commit();
    }

 public void Update(T entity)
    {
        try
        {

            DbEntityEntry _dbEntityEntry = this.DbContext.Entry(entity);

            DbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            if (_dbEntityEntry.State == EntityState.Detached)
                this.dbSet.Attach(entity);

            _dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;

        }
  }
public bool Commit()
    {
        try
        {
            this.DbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

And the childrens are not change but sortOrder success to change.

Why is it happening?

EDIT:

I found solution the problem because the children objects are dummy and need to get the "real" object from the DB

```
   public void SaveMenu(List<Menu> newMenu)
    {
        foreach(Menu _addMenu in newMenu)
        {
            List<Menu> listMenu = new List<Menu>();
            foreach (Menu child in _addMenu.Childrens)
            {
                Menu _menuFromDB = this.Query().FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == child.Id);
                _menuFromDB.SortOrder = child.SortOrder;
                listMenu.Add(_menuFromDB);
            }
            _addMenu.Childrens = listMenu;
            this.Update(_addMenu,null);
        }
        this.Commit();
    }
```

Comment: that self answer works for me.